# Linq to Entities .net4 EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have Bikes, Seats and BikeSeats tables. BikeSeats is mapper table, composite key from BikeID and SeatID, no other columns in it.

All of this is mapped in EF, .net 4 in only Bike, Seat (and bike.Seats and seat.Bikes)

I want to get all seat types that red color bikes would have:

```
    select distinct s.* 
    from seats s
          left join bikeSeats bs on s.seatID = bs.seatId
    where bs.bikeId in (select distinct bikeId from bikes where color=red)
```

using Linq to Entities

The really hard part for me is that the BikeSeats does not exist, it's been mapped to basically bike.Seats and/or seat.Bikes (which EF does because the table has only 2 ids)

Any help to convert this query would be so so appreciated

Thanks 
--MB

Comment: FYI: I edited the question to say LINQ to Entities instead of LINQ to SQL, since the OP indicates he is using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary, my dear Boisson:

```
var seatsOnRedBikes = ctx.Seats.Where(s => s.Bikes.Any(b => b.Color == "Red"));
```

Comment: the query looks like a work of genius and you even insulted me while calling me dear! that's genius. im obviously missing something in linq. there was some comment re eager fetching that confused me but it disappeared. also, there is no distinct, but it somehow works.... thanks again

Comment: @Massive Boisson - i removed my answer and upvoted this, because this is correct (and mine wasnt). Eager loading is required when you want to retrieve all of the relevant records in a relationship (like a LEFT OUTER JOIN, without a filter). But since he's filtering here, it's not required and EF will "just work out" what is required.

Comment: @Massive Boisson: No insult intended: I just wanted to point out that it's tempting to come up with something very complicated to solve problems like this, when it should be simple. This is a direct translation of "I want all seats where any of their bikes have "Red" as their color." Distinct isn't necessary because ctx.Seats will only return one row for each seat in the first place. The eager fetching comments were over-complicating the issue, so you can disregard them.

Answer (score 0):

First have to declare an instance of your entity i don't know what your entity name is let's for example say it's BikeSeatEntity

```
List<Seat> GetSeats()
        {
            using (BikeSeatEntity bsEntity = new BikeSeatEntity())
            {
                var seats = from s in bsEntity.Seats.Include("Bikes").Where(s => s.Bike.Color = "Red")
                            select s;
                List<Seat> seatsList = seats.ToList();
                return seatsList;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

if this don't work for you please describe more about your entities.

Comment: `s => s.Bike` is `s => s.Bikes`, which is a collection, so doing `.Color` on that won't work.